# Blur in Java docs in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, virtualbox, javadoc, ubuntu-16.04, eclipse-neon

I am running eclipse Neon inside Ubuntu 16.04 Virtual box. When I move my cursor over java docs I am facing blur text. Please find below screenshot [Snapshot of Eclipse with Javadocs view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LMqOR.png)

Please suggest how to overcome this blurred text.

Thanks!!!

Comment: I also added following lines in eclipse.ini before vmargs line. 

--launcher.GTK_version
2

it didn't work.

Comment: Also, Please note that I could see javadocs very well with disabled 3d acceleration mode in virtualbox settings. However, when I turn on 3d acceleration, then javadocs are completely blurred as in the attached image. Hope this information helps to understand this issue.